# How to handle error from `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)`

Tags: swift, avcapturesession

In most implementations of the `photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)` I have seen (including [Apple's own example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app)), on error the function simply logs the error and returns, e.g.:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    // ...
    if let error = error {
        print("Error capturing photo: \(error)")
        return
    }
    // ...
}
```

... and this is similar to what I have at the moment.

**First problem**: I was able to observe error in `photoOutput` only a few times, but in all cases it happened when the camera was actually not usable (it was not possible to take any more images with current capture session). For example in one case camera showed a black screen.

Hence clearly just logging the error is not a good idea. But what is the better way: will restarting capture session help? Or should our code treat such case as "user no longer has access to camera"?

And this brings us to the

**Second problem**: I cannot reproduce camera malfunction on demand, so cannot investigate the proper course of action in this case. The mocking of the error is not suitable here, since mocked error will not tell me if restarting capture session is going to help with real camera issue.

So looking for recommendations on how to handle errors in `photoOutput`, besides logging them, or how to recreate "hardware" issues with camera, so I can investigate the proper course of actions.